# I need a transparent rj45 to wifi bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I need transparent platform independent rj45 to wifi bridge- does such a thing exist?

I want to connect a computer to the device via an Ethernet cable, the device will then bind the IP of the computer's NIC to itself and connect to a wifi router.

I don't want to have to install software or drivers for the device and I want other devices on the wifi segment to be able to ping the computer via its NIC's address.

I have seem some devices like this, but I think they are just APs running in client mode. That won't work for me because, while the computer will be able to ping other devices the other devices won't be able to directly ping my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are usually called "wireless bridges", but many AP models can act as stations and connect to an existing AP (look for "station mode" or "client mode" in the documentation).

(Though see the note below about "AP" vs "router".)

> won't work for me because, while the computer will be able to ping other devices the other devices won't be able to directly ping my computer.

That's complete nonsense. Bridges are transparent in both directions.

But often people use the term "AP" for a consumer wireless router, which are actually a combined IP router & Wi-Fi AP. It's the *router* part, not the AP part, which blocks the incoming access.

---

There's one exception though – although bridges are supposed to be completely transparent, due to the way Wi-Fi works they will still have to hide the computer's *MAC* address.

To avoid that, you would have to enable the "WDS bridge" option in both the client *and* the actual AP. However, even if WDS-bridge mode is not available, this generally won't be a problem at IP level – things like DHCP will still work fine.